# operation on Ord., Exp., Dri. generating functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, generating-functions

The ordinary, exponential and Dirichlet generating functions for a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq0}$ are given (at least on the formal side), respectively, by
$$F(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n, \qquad E(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}, \qquad
G(s)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a_n}{n^s}.$$
See [Herb Wilf's book](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) for an excellent reference, which is freely available online.

Consider the partial sums $b_n=\sum_{k=0}^na_k$ and ask for the three corresponding generating functions.

(1) For $f(x)=\sum_nb_nx^n$, one solves $F(x)=f(x)-xf(x)$.

(2) For $e(x)=\sum_nb_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$, one solves $e'(x)-e(x)=E'(x)$.

> **Question.**
>
> (3) How does one find $g(s)=\sum_n\frac{b_n}{n^s}$ from $G(s)$?

Comment: Wouldn't you get something like $a_1\zeta(s) + a_2(\zeta(s)-1) + a_3 (\zeta(s) - 1 - 2^{-s}) + ...$. I think solving in terms of $G$ might be impossible; that might be the closest expression involving $a_n$. What's interesting is that this kind of expresses $g(s)$ involving partial sums of $G(s)$, which is neat.

Comment: "Difficult? yes. Impossible? no." We just need the right ideas.

Comment: Would be easy to consider $G(x,s)=\sum_{n>0} \frac{a_n}{(x+n)^s}$.